# Download data and save it locally

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm having a problem regarding saving files from a downloadable link to the phone's local storage. My plan is to create a `Button` that will download [a file](https://venturebeat.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/google-flutter-logo.png?fit=578%2C289&strip=all).

Then, I want to *save it* to the *phone's **internal storage***, so that it will be *accessible* from the *phone's **file storage system***. I've tried to implement it using `SharedPreferences`, but it wasn't really what I was looking for. Can someone enlighten me on how to execute this feature?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

no need to use SharedPreferences because it is a key/value database . in your case you are trying to write a file to disk so you need some libraries :

- [HTTP client](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/package-http_http/package-http_http-library.html) so you can Make a network request
- [dart:io](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/dart-io-library.html) library so you can write files to disk
- [path_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider) plugin to find locations on the filesystem
- [dart:async](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/dart-async-library.html) so your UI will not freeze while downloading the file

and here is a snipest code :

```
static var httpClient = new HttpClient();
Future<File> _downloadFile(String url, String filename) async {
  var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
  var response = await request.close();
  var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
  String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  File file = new File('$dir/$filename');
  await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
  return file;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to implement this snippet to my project, imported the necessary libraries, call it  inside the `onPressed` attribute of my `Button`, and added a `String` variable for the url and the filename, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I was running it in debug mode. When I clicked the button, nothing showed up in the debug console. And I also checked the dir where the file was supposed to be saved in, which is: `Android/data/com.example.downloadexample`, the folder was empty

Comment: can you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739537/print-pdf-from-responsebody-flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package [dio](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio) for file downloads:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart'; 

Dio dio = new Dio(); 
Response response = 
    await dio.get("https://venturebeat.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/google-flutter-logo.png?fit=578%2C289&strip=all"); 
print(response.data);
```

Or use Flutters [HttpClient](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html):

```
new HttpClient().get('https://venturebeat.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/google-flutter-logo.png?fit=578%2C289&strip=all', 80, saveLocation)
.then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
.then((HttpClientResponse response) { 
response.transform(utf8.decoder)
.listen((contents) { 
// Do something with your data 
});
});
```

For getting the paths where you want to save the files check [this](https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files/) out. And if you want to save the url where the file was downloaded with SharedPreferences check out this [link](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) and create a StringList on your device with one url in each.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I'll try out these libraries and get back to you when I succeed or failed

Comment: I tried running dio's example app (which can be found [here](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/example/download.dart)) and I ran into a `path` problem. When I used `./example/flutter.png` as the download path, `I/flutter (10109): FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = './example/flutter.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)` shows up. And when I used `(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path` which produces `/data/user/0/com.example.downloadexample/app_flutter`, no error showed up, but the file wasn't there. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @sentinel any success with this? Struggling with the same issue here. I want the downloaded files to be generally  available in the device's Download Folder. Had the same error with dio.

Comment: @sentinel You probably need this:
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
...
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();